# $ \sum_{m=0}^\infty {{n+m-1}\choose{m}}(s(1-p))^m p^n = ({\frac{p}{1-s(1-p)}})^n$ if $|s|<(1-p)^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation

I am looking for tips how to solve this sum:
$$ \sum_{m=0}^\infty {{n+m-1}\choose{m}}(s(1-p))^m p^n  = ({\frac{p}{1-s(1-p)}})^n$$ $$|s|<(1-p)^{-1}$$
I suspect it must be somehow linked to geometric series but can´t see how. I tried working backward but don`t really know what to do with sum like
$$(p \sum_{m=0}^\infty(s(1-p))^m)^n$$

Comment: For $n=1$ the sum is easy, have you tried induction for higher $n$?

Comment: If I understand you correctlly:result is not given,  just wrote it here so people know solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|s|<(1-p)^{-1} \Rightarrow |s(1-p)|<1$, the sum converges and following identity can be used:
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty {{n+m-1}\choose{m}}x^m=\frac{1}{(1-x)^n},$$
from which the result instantly follows.
$$p^n\sum_{m=0}^\infty {{n+m-1}\choose{m}}(s(1-p))^m=\frac{p^n}{(1-s(1-p))^n}$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you pleas explain identity: $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty {{n+m-1}\choose{m}}x^m=\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}$$ . I was looking for something like this but could not find it.

Comment: Don't really know the name for identity,but theres a proof for general case:
 [link]http://www.gotohaggstrom.com/The%20binomial%20series%20for%20negative%20integral%20exponents.pdf . I only know combinatorial proof which is kinda hard to explain here.